# Link doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

We have an issue with a link not working properly when clicked.

When hovering the button the link shows fine but nothing happens when you click it. (Right-click > Open in new tab works fine)

You can see what I mean on the themes example site [here](http://demos.artbees.net/jupiter/blog/blog-classic/), it is the little comment buttons with a small number hovering over it.

I've tried to fool around in the CSS and PHP files but I can't really make much sense of what the issue is.

Comment: Your link is broken. You should be showing the code directly here instead or in a jsfiddle perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `e.preventDefault();` in your `scripts-vendors.js` file keeping the link from working properly.

[image]

It looks like it's meant to scroll to an anchor link on the same page, but since this is actually linking to a different page, it doesn't operate properly.

I suggest to override that functionality with a custom script file and some adjustment to the HTML. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and help! I'm not that much into scripts but I managed to make it work with the information provided. :-)

May I ask if something in the source code made you look in the script file, or if you used any tools to locate the issue? I'd like to learn more so I can hopefully resolve it on my own next time.

Comment: @BrianB good to hear. The way I sorted it was by looking at the link and noticing the `#comments` at the URL. Then I realized it was a different page. After knowing that I inspected it with Firebug via Firefox, but you can use any inspector tool. When inspecting the element you have the ability to see what "events" are attached to it. When I inspected the event tied to it, I saw the issue. I hope that all helps! Don't forget to mark it as the answer, please. Thanks!